# ViewCellRenderer / Handler not working for Maui

Tags: xamarin.forms, mapping, handler, maui

I am trying to create a custom ViewcellHandler bit confusing seeing as its still called a viewCellRenderer.

In my code at the bottom, neither of my mapped values is hit when their values are updated. I know for my other handlers I have to specify a base alongside the constructor but this will not let me do that.

i.e.

```
    public CustomViewCellHandler() : base(CustomViewCellMapper)
    {

    }
```

As well as that the OnPropertyChanged event is not hit either.

Ideally, I would like to get one if not both working/understand why they won't work.

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility.Platform.Android;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.Compatibility;
using Microsoft.Maui.Handlers;
using Microsoft.Maui.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Maui.Platform;
using NGT.Views.Customised.Controls;
using ViewCellRenderer = Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.Compatibility.ViewCellRenderer;
using global::Android.Graphics;
using Color = Android.Graphics.Color;

namespace NGT.CustomHandlers;

public class CustomViewCellHandler : ViewCellRenderer
{
    private CustomViewCell customViewCell;

    private static bool selected;

    private static Color selectedColor;

    /// <summary>
    /// The Property mapper.
    /// </summary>
    public static IPropertyMapper<CustomViewCell, CustomViewCellHandler> CustomViewCellMapper
        = new PropertyMapper<CustomViewCell, CustomViewCellHandler>(ViewCellRenderer.Mapper)
        {
            [nameof(CustomViewCell.SelectedBackgroundColor)] = MapColour,
            [nameof(CustomViewCell.IsSelected)] = MapSelection,
        };

    public CustomViewCellHandler()
    {

    }

    private static void MapSelection(CustomViewCellHandler handler, CustomViewCell view)
    {
        selected = !selected;

        if (selected)
        {
            handler.PlatformView.SetBackgroundColor(selectedColor);
        }
        else
        {
            handler.PlatformView.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Transparent);
        }
    }

    private static void MapColour(CustomViewCellHandler handler, CustomViewCell view)
    {
        selectedColor = view.SelectedBackgroundColor.ToAndroid();
    }

    public override void UpdateValue(string property)
    {
        base.UpdateValue(property);
    }

    protected override void ConnectHandler(Android.Views.View platformView)
    {
        base.ConnectHandler(platformView);

        this.customViewCell = this.VirtualView as CustomViewCell;

        this.customViewCell.PropertyChanged += OnCellPropertyChanged;
    }

    protected override void DisconnectHandler(Android.Views.View platformView)
    {
        this.VirtualView.PropertyChanged -= OnCellPropertyChanged;

        base.DisconnectHandler(platformView);
    }

    protected override void OnCellPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        base.OnCellPropertyChanged(sender, args);

        if (args.PropertyName == "IsSelected")
        {
            selected = !selected;

            if (selected)
            {
                var extendedViewCell = sender as CustomViewCell;

                this.PlatformView.SetBackgroundColor(selectedColor);
            }
            else
            {
                this.PlatformView.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Transparent);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I might have to debug this to be sure why this is not working but just to be sure could you check the .net GitHub to find any existing issues on this

Comment: @FreakyAli I have looked and can't see anything, do you suppose this is a bug then? I only ask as I don't have any experience with this so not sure if I am just doing it wrong

Comment: Well, I am not 100% sure but I don't see you making any silly mistakes, so my guess is that you aren't making any, I would recommend two things, Make sure you have registered your handler, Kinda like [that](https://github.com/FreakyAli/Maui.FreakyControls/blob/044731db6ad0a215abe7073d2f1274666868c0b2/MAUI.FreakyControls/MAUI.FreakyControls/Shared/Extensions/Extensions.cs#L36) and if yes then make sure you are using it correctly in your ListView. If yes again then just raise a bug with a sample project on Maui Git and hope they respond in time